# JuiceUI Dialog Post Back Script Error: Circular reference in value argument not supported

Tags: dialog, postback, circular-reference, juice-ui

I am getting a strange script error on post back if I have a JuiceUI Dialog control on the page, regardless if it is used or not.  I can't find anything out there on this, so I am sure that I am doing something wrong.  Can any one provide any help?  Below is my .aspx page, there is no code behind.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div id="_DefaultDiv" class="basic-dialog" title="Basic dialog" runat="server">
    <p>
        This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog
        window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<juice:Dialog ID="Dialog1" TargetControlID="_DefaultDiv" AutoOpen="false" runat="server" />
<p>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="OpenDialog();" />
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OpenDialog() {
        $(".basic-dialog").dialog("open")
    }

</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Circular reference in value argument not supported
Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836474(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This might cause because an attempt has been made to invoke JSON.stringify with a value that is not valid. The value argument, an array or object, contains a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out a new fork named [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew) that resolves a lot of issues like this. If there's still an issue, I'd be happy to work with you to fix it.

Comment: Is JuiceUI dead?  Have they stopped dev?